# ImmutableHashSet RemoveWhere

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

`HashSet<T>` has `public int RemoveWhere(Predicate<T> match)`;

However `ImmutableHashSet<T>` does not.

I end up doing:

```
var x = ImmutableHashSet<int>.Empty.Add(5).Add(3);

var next = x.Where(i => i>4).ToImmutableHashSet();
```

Which works but is ugly and mainly I'm not sure about its effiency ?

Is there a better way ?
Is there a reason `ImmutableHashSet` does not have `RemoveWhere` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why it does not, but you easily just [copy the implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,8cca6efd5ab31fdf) as a extension method yourself. You only need to convert the `ImmutableHashSet` to a `ImmutableHashSet.Builder` and the logic can be exactly the same.

```
namespace System.Collections.Immutable {
  public static class ExtensionMethods {
    public static ImmutableHashSet<T> RemoveWhere<T>(this ImmutableHashSet<T> hashSet, Predicate<T> match) => 
      hashSet.RemoveWhere(match, out _);

    public static ImmutableHashSet<T> RemoveWhere<T>(this ImmutableHashSet<T> hashSet, Predicate<T> match, out int numRemoved) {
      if (match == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(match));
      var hashSetBuilder = hashSet.ToBuilder();
      numRemoved = 0;
      foreach (var value in hashSet) if (match(value) && hashSetBuilder.Remove(value)) numRemoved++;
      return hashSetBuilder.ToImmutable();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! which namespace should this extension method belong to ?

Comment: Anywhere you feel like, namespace does not matter for extension methods so long as you have a `using` statement with that namespace in the .cs file you want to use the extension method in.

Comment: ok I'll use namespace System.Collections.Immutable .. also shouldn't it be public static class ExtensionMethods ?

Comment: also the code does not compile, you define numRemoved twice ?

Comment: yes, this entire post was written in the browser and may contain compiler errors